# Lotus Script NotesRichTextItem Limit?

Tags: lotusscript

The limit of NotesRichTextItem Limit should be 1G, right?

I append the doclink by this:
Call rtitem_temp.appenddoclink(doc, "")

it works fine if the number of doclink is less.
but if many doclink wwere appended, then early part of the doclink were replaced.

It seems that there is a limit of this. Am I right?
(Or I did sth wrongly?)

Please advise. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There's a 64 Kb limit on the paragraph size. It is hard to say exactly, how many doclinks may exceed the paragraph size limit. You may experiment that. To solve this problem asap, add new line (start new paragraph) after each doclink:

```
Call rtitem_temp.appenddoclink(doc, "")
Call rtitem_temp.AddNewLine( 1 )
```